# Is there a way to read a csv column when its name contains spaces in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, csv

I use d3.js library to read a CSV in Angular. Here's how I read it.

```
d3.csv('../assets/datasets/tests-per-million.csv').then((data: any) => {
  this.testsData = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.testsData.length; i++) {
    this.testCountries.push(this.testsData[i].Entity.split(' ')[0]);
    this.testDates.push(this.testsData[i].Date);
    this.cumulativeTests.push(this.testsData[i].Cumulative);
  }
});
```

The problem is that the last column of the CSV contains spaces on its name. Here is a sample of a CSV row.

```
Entity: "Australia - units unclear"
Code: ""
Date: "Mar 22, 2020"
Cumulative total tests per million: "5632.53024026095"
```

I have successfully read the three first columns but I cannot catch the last one which contains space on its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the key (`Cumulative total tests per million`) has spaces, you need to access the JSON using bracket notation:

`this.cumulativeTests.push(this.testsData[i]['Cumulative total tests per million']);`